# How to install Epson XP-235 scanner's driver

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, scanner, epson

My computer runs under Lubuntu and I'm a complete newbie about Linux and computers in general (I know how to Ctrl+Alt+T and then I'm lost if I don't have precise help).

My EPSON XP-235 scanner just doesn't want to be installed. SimpleScan doesn't find it when plugged with the USB. The CD doesn't want to work either. I tried to find a driver for the printer and after hours of trying many things it finally worked, but the scanner doesn't.

I could probably fix it easily but I don't understand what to do when. I downloaded imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb and tried to follow the README instructions :

```
tar xaf imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb.tar.gz cd imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb ./install.sh
```

But i get the following message :

```
tar: imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb.tar.gz : open impossible : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So HOW ??? Thank you !

Comment: This is the only tutorial that made the scanner work for me: http://mark.schofield.free.fr/articles/computing/ubuntu/ubuntu_epson_xp-235.php

Comment: I download from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/ XP245 the scanner driver , than install with command line : ./install.sh
it looks OK ... v.3.55.0 (06-03-2019) imagescan found the device but unable to save with none of known format , ... the file is opening , than the system is remove it ? simplescan detect the scanner but unable to start it ... xsane is working ! but i dont like the gui On 16.04 & 19.04 the same happening ! The user is in sane and scanner group ! Is some udev rule is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you want to unzip the archive (.tar.gz file):

```
tar xvf imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb.tar.gz
```

Once that's done, you should either have a folder named something similar to that file, or a file, which I expect to end with .deb. You can view the files in your current directory by typing `ls -ltr`, this will also show more information about them, and sort them by modified date, with the most recent at the bottom. Locate the .deb file, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.10-1.1.13.x86.deb
```

Naturally, if the .deb file has a different name, you will need to change this command. Read the output from this, sometimes it will say "You have unmet dependencies", this means basically that dpkg couldn't handle the deb file since it doesn't know how to install other stuff which is required, so to fix it I tend to do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will prompt you for Y/N, when it does, you should read it. It will say either "The following packages will be installed", or "The following packages will be removed", and it will list the imagescan package. If it says they will be installed, you're golden. If it says they will be removed, let me know and I'll try remember what I normally do from there.